Copy a Specified Folder with XCOPY
If I specify a folder in XCOPY, it only copies the contents. I want it to copy the folder itself.
Tried running:
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %F in ('type directories.txt') do (xcopy /hrkvyei "%F" "D:\Destination\")
Where directories.txt contains:
C:\A\Aardvark
C:\A\Aaron A. Aaronsen

But it just dumps everything from the Aardvark folder into D:\Destination, instead of D:\Desination\A\Aardvark.
So then I tried: for /f "tokens=* delims=" %F in ('type directories.txt') do (xcopy /hrkvyei "%F" "D:\Destination\%~pF\")
But that dumps everything from the Aardvark folder into D:\Destination\A, instead of D:\Destination\A\Aardvark.
How do I do this?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy

If I specify a folder in XCOPY, it only copies the contents. I want it to copy the folder itself.
You need to use the /s option:
/S Copy folders and subfolders

Source: Xcopy - Copy files and folders - Windows CMD - SS64.com
In your case:
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %F in ('type directories.txt') do (xcopy "%F"\* "D:\Destination" /s)

Notes:

Add other options as required.

The options always go at the end:
Syntax XCOPY source [destination] [options]


Source: Xcopy - Copy files and folders - Windows CMD - SS64.com

Further Reading

An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com
Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com

